# Monoepoxidation of 1,2-dimethylcyclohexa-1,4-diene using m-CPBA

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation, chemoselectivity

> What is the product formed when 1,2-dimethylcyclohexa-1,4-diene undergoes epoxidation with one equivalent of *m*-CPBA (*meta*-chloroperbenzoic acid)?
>
> [image: Epoxidation of 1,2-dimethylcyclohexa-1,4-diene with m-CPBA]

In the epoxidation mechanism, the π-electrons of the double bond attack *m*-CPBA:

[image: Mechanism of epoxidation with m-CPBA]

So, methyl groups attached to the double bond should increase its nucleophilicity. On the other hand, since it is a nucleophilic attack, the methyl groups should also cause considerable steric hindrance. So what should the answer be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The interaction of the alkene with *m*-CPBA is primarily nucleophilic/electrophilic in nature, i.e. the π MO of the alkene attacks the O–O σ* orbital. Therefore, the more electron-rich alkene (i.e. more highly substituted alkene) preferentially reacts.

With methyl groups there probably isn't too much steric hindrance. *m*-CPBA approaches above/below the alkene and doesn't directly attack over the methyl groups.

Indeed, the monoepoxidation of 1,2-dimethylcyclohexa-1,4-diene is reported to proceed selectively at the more electron-rich tetrasubstituted double bond ([*J. Org. Chem.* **2006,** *71* (4), 1653–1657](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo052357x)):

[image: Epoxidation to form 1,6-dimethyl-7-oxabicyclo[4.1.0]hept-3-ene]

Comment: How tolerant is this against aromatisation? You have a 1,4-cyclohexadiene, you look at it in the wrong way and it gives you a benzene ring.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン there's one record of this substrate being oxidised, with DDQ instead of mCPBA. I suppose it  may form 1,2-dimethylbenzene if the epoxide is opened  - form the diol then dehydrate