# Regioselectivity of the Hydroboration and Epoxidation of Limonene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, regioselectivity

[image]

Could someone help me out with the most likely major products for each reaction?

1 eq. of reagent is used for both reactions, so my initial thought was that both processes would only occur at the C=C double bond on the 6-membered ring as that one is more substituted and therefore more electron rich compared to the C=C bond at the bottom. However, the C=C bond at the bottom is less hindered so I was wondering if maybe sterics was a more important factor when considering regioselectivity for either one or both reactions.

Answer (score 4):

Sterics is the deciding factor in hydroboration which occurs at the least hindered carbon, thus you get the primary alcohol from limonene. The hydroboration of limonene is discussed [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/hydroboration)

MCPBA selectively oxidises the more substituted alkene [source here](https://chemistryportal.net/alkenes-reactions-epoxidation.html) so with limonene the selectivity is the reverse of the hydroboration and the cyclohexene double bond is epoxidised.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a reason why sterics is the deciding factor for hydroboration but not for epoxidation? Especially as BH3 (less bulky) is used instead of BHR2 as the reagent.

Comment: @SashaJ  Does this answer your question? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74005/monoepoxidation-of-1-2-dimethylcyclohexa-1-4-diene-using-m-cpba

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you for sharing. I think I understand why epoxidation occurs at the more substituted electron rich bond, however I am still unsure why hydroboration does not follow the same selectivity. Isn't BH3 also acting as an electrophile, so shouldn't it also be attracted to the more electron rich bond? I get why sterics would be the deciding factor if the hydroboration reagent used was bulkier, but in this case it isn't.

Comment: @SashaJ  I cannot immediately answer this. I think it deserves to be a new question.